# Formatting a nan float in python

Tags: python, string-formatting

I'm trying to use string.format on a 'nan' float.

Here's the description of the 'g' option from the [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6/library/string.html).

> General format. This prints the number as a fixed-point number, unless the number is too large, in which case it switches to 'e' exponent notation. Infinity and NaN values are formatted as inf, -inf and nan, respectively.

And here's what i get trying it in the interpreter (Python 2.6):

```
>>> print "{0:g}".format(float('nan'))
-1.#IND
```

As I understand the documentation, the output should be "nan".

Is this a bug or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: What platform and which version of Python are you using?

Comment: Platform's Windows 7 and Python v. 2.6.6 (32-bit)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`repr(float)` was fixed in Python 2.6 and Python 3.0; see http://bugs.python.org/issue1635; however `str.format` was not fixed until the 2.7 branch; see http://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/c5e0d9beebf9 and http://bugs.python.org/issue1580.

I'd recommend seeing if `"{0!r}"` works for you; that *should* call into the non-broken `repr` code.

If you need to use `"{0:g}"` format spec, you could try subclassing `float` and overriding `__format__`:

```
class FixFloat(float):
    def __format__(self, format_spec):
        return 'nan' if math.isnan(self) else float.__format__(self, format_spec)

"{0:g}".format(FixFloat(1.2345e9))
'1.2345e+09'
"{0:g}".format(FixFloat(float('nan')))
'nan'
```

Comment: I am using Python 2.6. Would you care to develop your answer a little more?

Comment: Are the `Versions` listed in the bug report the versions where it was discovered, or the versions where it was fixed? I suspect the former. It works for me in 2.7.

Comment: The command `"{0!r}".format(float('nan'))` does produce the expected output ('nan'). However, I'd like to use the 'g' option behavior. Any ideas how that can be done? I'm thinking of a conditional check `if math.isnan(num): print this; else: print that` but it seems rather unpythonic...

Comment: And I'm accepting your answer because the question was effectively solved plus the discussions in the links you provide are very interesting indeed.

Comment: Very nice! Now I just have to figure out a way to implement it without too much work, I've got floats all over the place... But thanks!