# Python string.format() : formatting nans as 'some text'?

Tags: python, format, string-formatting, nan

I am using `string.format()` to format some numbers into strings. Does `format()` have an option to show a specific text (e.g. 'not available') instead of nan? I couldn't find it. Or would I have to do the replacement manually?

To clarify the point raised in the comments, a question by a similar title but different context [was asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849158/formatting-a-nan-float-in-python). My question is different because the author of that question wanted to get 'nan' as output, but was getting something else because of a bug that's since been fixed.

Instead, I want to understand if format() has a built-in option to replace 'nan' with some other text. Of course I do fully appreciate that I can make the replacement manually myself, but was just wondering if this was a built-in option of `format()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting a nan float in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849158/formatting-a-nan-float-in-python)

Comment: I did look at that question, but it is different. The author of that question wanted to get 'nan' as output, but was getting something else because of a bug which has been fixed. Instead, I get 'nan' but want to understand if format() has an option to display something other than 'nan'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve this with `format`, or at least, I don't know how. The only way I know it can be done is to subclass `float`, like this:

```
from math import isnan

class myfloat(float):
    def __str__(self):
        if isnan(self):
            return 'Not available'
        else:
            return super(myfloat, self).__str__()
```

Following which, you can get:

```
>>> a = myfloat('nan')
>>> a
nan
>>> print(a)
Not available
```

If you want the representation of `a` to show up as "Not available" on the interpreter, then you'll have to override `__repr__` instead.

**Alternate hack**

Why not just call `replace` on the formatted string? (assuming there's no other string portions in there that read "nan").

```
>>> a = float('nan')
>>> print('This number is ' + ('%0.2f' % a).replace('nan', 'not available'))
This number is not available
```

Comment: I ma, in fact, calling replacer() in my script. I was just wondering if format() had a built-in option - more of a curiosity than anything else, really. Thanks!